# Iterate through many directories in Python [Python3]

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

So I have been working on a program that needs to run through each file in a particular directory and do things depending on the file. That bit is done (code below), however I really need to expand this so that I can parse in as many directories as needed and have the program cycle through them all sequentially. My code is as follows (apologies for really clunky, bad code):

```
def createTemplate( self, doType = 0, bandNameL = None, bandName430 = None ):

    '''
    Loads the archive of each file in a directory.
    Depending on the choice made on initialization, a template will be
    created for one band (of the user's choosing) or all bands.
    Templates are saved in self.directory (either CWD or whatever the user
    wishes) as 1D numpy arrays, .npy. If arguments are not provided for the
    template names (without the .npy suffix), default names will be used.

    Useage of the doType parameter: 0 (default) does both bands and returns a tuple.
    1 does only the L-band.
    2 does only the 430-band.
    '''

    print( "Beginning template creation..." )

    # Initialize the file names if given
    nameL = str( bandNameL ) + ".npy"
    name430 = str( bandName430 ) + ".npy"

    # Set the templates to empty arrays
    self.templateProfile430, self.templateProfileL = [], []

    # Set the call counters for the creation scripts to 0
    self._templateCreationScript430.__func__.counter = 0
    self._templateCreationScriptL.__func__.counter = 0

    # Cycle through each file in the stored directory
    for file in os.listdir( self.directory ):
        # Set the file to be a global variable in the class for use elsewhere
        self.file = file

        # Check whether the file is a fits file
        if self.file.endswith( ".fits" ) or self.file.endswith( ".refold" ):

            # Check if the file is a calibration file (not included in the template)
            if self.file.find( 'cal' ) == -1:

                # Open the fits file header
                hdul = fits.open( self.directory + self.file )

                # Get the frequency band used in the observation.
                frequencyBand = hdul[0].header[ 'FRONTEND' ]

                # Close the header once it's been used or the program becomes very slow.
                hdul.close()

                # Check which band the fits file belongs to
                if frequencyBand == 'lbw' or frequencyBand == 'L_Band':

                    if doType == 0 or doType == 1:
                        self.templateProfileL = self._templateCreationScriptL()

                        # Check if a save name was provided
                        if bandNameL == None:
                            np.save( self.directory + "Lbandtemplate.npy", self.templateProfileL )
                        else:
                            np.save( self.directory + nameL, self.templateProfileL )
                    else:
                        print( "L-Band file" )

                elif frequencyBand == '430':

                    if doType == 0 or doType == 2:
                        self.templateProfile430 = self._templateCreationScript430()

                        # Check if a save name was provided
                        if bandName430 == None:
                            np.save( self.directory + "430bandtemplate.npy", self.templateProfile430 )
                        else:
                            np.save( self.directory + name430, self.templateProfile430 )
                    else:
                        print( "430-Band file" )

                else:
                    print( "Frontend is neither L-Band, nor 430-Band..." )

            else:
                print( "Skipping calibration file..." )


        else:
            print( "{} is not a fits file...".format( self.file ) )

    # Decide what to return based on doType
    if doType == 0:
        print( "Template profiles created..." )
        return self.templateProfileL, self.templateProfile430
    elif doType == 1:
        print( "L-Band template profile created..." )
        return self.templateProfileL
    else:
        print( "430-Band template profile created..." )
        return self.templateProfile430
```

So currently, it works perfectly for one directory but just need to know how to modify for multiple directories. Thank you anyone who can help.

**EDIT**: self.directory is initialised in the class initialisation, so maybe there's something that needs to be changed there instead:

```
class Template:

'''
Class for the creation, handling and analysis of pulsar template profiles.
Templates can be created for each frequency band of data in a folder which
can either be the current working directory or a folder of the user's
choosing.
'''

def __init__( self, directory = None ):

    # Check if the directory was supplied by the user. If not, use current working directory.
    if directory == None:
        self.directory = str( os.getcwd() )
    else:
        self.directory = str( directory )
```

Comment: you can get a list of files/directories at a path using `os.listdir(path)`

Comment: I have been using `os` for a few things such as `listdir` but I don't really understand it all too well.

Comment: Look at sys.argv, os.walk, etc. It's really unclear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Also, if you're having trouble understanding basic functions, you need a tutorial, not an SO question.

Comment: I absolutely need a tutorial but I can't find one that I understand. I'm really not good with programming. I just need a piece of code that will iterate through my directory, get to the end, then start iterating through a second directory and so on until I reach the end of all directories I specify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can run your logic in different directories:

```
>>> import os
>>> path = './python'
>>> for name in os.listdir(path) :
...     newpath = path+'/'+name
...     if os.path.isdir(newpath) :
...             for filename in os.listdir(newpath) :
...                     # do the work
...                     filepath = newpath + '/' + filename
...                     print(filepath)
...
```

Comment: Thank you. This is precisely what I needed. It's the same logic but when your brain is fried it can be hard to see that. Thanks again!